# Как реализована оптимистическая блокировка в Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Как реализована оптимистическая блокировка в Oracle?

Comment: оптимистическая блокировка внешнее от oracle понятие. Если хотите сделать такую блокировку сами проверяйте, что данные не изменились, например задавая все старые значения данных в `where` запроса `update`.

Comment: @Mike я это понимаю. Но может в оракл есть встроенная поддержка

Comment: Вообще я не знаю ни одной БД где была бы встроенная поддержка. И в чем она собственно могла бы заключаться, по вашему мнению.

Comment: @Mike например, какой-нибудь специальный оператор внутри транзакции осуществлял проверку что перед записью данных исходные данные не изменились, и осуществляющий откат транзакции

Comment: А с чем он будет сравнивать данные что бы понять что они не изменились ? Может приложение час назад их прочитало и показало на экране, а пользователь кофе пил и наконец через час запись нажал ...

Comment: @Mike Для этого оператор должен сохранить у себя считанные данные и перед записью их сравнить )

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Реализация оптимистической блокировки Ваша задача. Какого-то готового решения *Oracle* не предоставляет.

Для реализации оптимистической блокировки, воспользуйтесь версионированием данных. Добавьте в таблицу колонку, которая хранит счётчик изменений, например - `tsn` (*transaction sequence number*).
Этот счётчик должен изменятся при каждом обновлении данных, обычно автоматически в триггере - `:new.tsn := :old.tsn+1`.
При выполнении `update ... where ... tsn = saved_tsn` проверяется версия данных на изменение. Если update вернул 0 изменённых строк, значит данные были уже изменены в другой сессии и надо, или повторить транзакцию, или вернуть ошибку.

Аналогично можно пользоваться для этой цели:

- SCN (*system change number*) в псевдоколонке `ora_rowscn`
- колонкой с типом данных `timestamp` со временем последнего изменения

PS по умолчанию не отслеживается SCN на уровне row. Чтобы разрешить, таблицы должны быть определены так:

```
create table table_name rowdependencies ...
```